# ng-file-upload is not working in a bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, ui.bootstrap

I am using the ng-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

However, if I put the upload control into a directive and then display it in a modal, the upload does not work. I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.Upload.upload is not a function
```

Has anyone got it working in a modal dialog.

The modal is from angular.ui.bootstrap

Thanks

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Never mind. It was my own idiotic fault! I was injecting it incorrectly. Thanks